# Simple program giving segfault, unable to figure out the weird behaviour

Tags: c, integer, segmentation-fault, declaration

I am passing a txt file as command line argument and displaying it contents to the stdout. I want to create 5 integer variables (n,a,b,i,temp) at the start of the program. But the program is giving me a segfault once I declare more than 2 integers. If I comment out the third int declaration (int b), the program is running fine. Also, I am running on ubuntu.

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int n;
    int a;
    int b;
//  int i;
//  int temp;
    char *s;
    if(argc!=2){
            printf("not enough arguments provided!!\n");
            exit(-1);
    }
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    while((s=fgets(s,5,fp))!=NULL){
            n = atoi(s);
            printf("%d",n);
}
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: [gdb](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html) is your friend.

Comment: thanks nmichaels. i should definitely learn how to use gdb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `fgets(s,5,fp)` reads into an uninitialized pointer. You have to allocate storage which you place the read data into.

Change `char *s;` to `char s[5];`

Edit: Also change your while loop condition:

```
while(fgets(s,5,fp)) {
```

You should also check whether fopen() succeeds or fails.

Comment: if i comment out int b; the program is running fine .. it is displaying the contents of the txt file which i am passing as an argument.So, this wouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: if i change char *p to char s[5], i will have another problem here, function atoi expects a char * not char[5]

Comment: @user - Commenting out has nothing to do with the crash. Uninitialized pointer's behavior is undefined. So, it seems now that it is working when you comment something in the program. `char[]` gets converted to `char*` when passed. Array decays to a pointer when passed. So, using an array should not be a problem.

Comment: You can't take risks like that with C code. Your program doesn't segfault in that case due to sheer luck, on another machine or different compiler, it's just as likely to crash.

Comment: alright, when i change char *s; to char s[5]; even fgets function is throwing an error saying that it expects char *
error: incompatible types when assigning to type âchar[5]â from type âchar *â

Comment: @user- What compiler are you using ? Take a look at this example : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/

Comment: @Mahesh, I am using gcc compiler. Thanks a lot guys. I am new to stackoverflow and I'm really amazed by how quick i could get help :)

Answer (score 0):

`s` is an uninitialized pointer. While on call to `fgets`, the first argument needs to be a location to which the contents can be copied to. `s` is pointing no where( or garbage ) and trying to copy in to that location is what causing the error.

Just declare:

```
char s[1] ; // Instead of char *s ; or declare it as an character array to 
            // to the size you may require.
```